# Browsed file name is not getting displayed in textbox

Tags: php, html, css

```
<input title="Browse" type="file" name="file" onchange="this.parentNode.nextSibling.value = this.value.split('\\').pop().split('/').pop()">

Browse
```

From the above code i am uploading file and uploaded file is working fine but when i click upload button the current browsed file name is not getting displayed in the text box which i provided.

Comment: where is the text box

Comment: <label for="file" class="input input-file">
                                  <input type="text" placeholder="Upload Students file" readonly="">
                                  <div class="button"><input title="Browse" type="file" name="file" onchange="this.parentNode.nextSibling.value = this.value.split('\\').pop().split('/').pop()">Browse
                                  </div>
                              </label>

Answer (score 0):

Since you'll display the file-name in a separate text-box and you won't use the default filename display. It's better to create a `button` and have it call the file-upload using `onclick`. After that you can get the file-name and assign it to the text-box you created using the javascript below.

javascript:

```
var filename;
document.getElementById('fileInput').onchange = function () {
filename = this.value.split(String.fromCharCode(92));
document.getElementById("fileText").value = filename[filename.length-1];
};
```

HTML:

```
<label for="file" class="input input-file">   
<input type="text" id="fileText" placeholder="Upload Students file"   readonly="" />
<input type="file" id="fileInput" style="display: none;"  />
<input type="button" value="Choose File"   onclick="document.getElementById('fileInput').click();" />
</label>
```

I've made a quick demo for you here: http://jsfiddle.net/x9L8etfg/

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

you have to parse to the parent of text node, then only you can set the value.

use this:

```
onchange="this.parentNode.parentNode.childNodes[1].value = this.value.split('\\').pop().split('/').pop()"
```

Comment: Thanks.  can u tell me how i need to parse the parent node?

Comment: What are you looking for ?